# How to get a JavaScript variable value from HTML using AngleSharp?

Tags: javascript, c#, anglesharp

I have a website url, that returns some html like below, and I want to get value of `Trade` variable. I am using `AngleSharp` library in `ASP.NET Core v2.0`

```
<div> <p>html content</p> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var Trade=[['20190717','145'],['1455','5552']];
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

For such simple cases `AngleSharp.Js` should be able to help you.

Install it via NuGet `Install-Package AngleSharp.Js`.

Your configuration should be similar to (excluding any options you've used already - keep those in there):

```
var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithJs();
```

Now you could access some global JS variable in an existing `document` (instance of an `IDocument`) from a valid `context` (instance of an `IBrowsingContext`).

```
var engine = context.GetService<JsScriptingService>();
var jsValue = engine.EvaluateScript(document, "Trade");
```

Hope that helps!